# Hiding implementation details with .h and .m in objc

Tags: objective-c

I'm confused about something. If in your .h file you have:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *categories;
```

and then in the .m you have:

```
@interface MyClass ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *categories;
@end
```

If I want to later set categories in the .m file, I can do:

```
[self setCategories:[NSArray arrayWithArray:categories]];
```

But then Xcode complains that `incompatible pointer types sending NSArray to NSMutableArray.`  I'm basically trying to hide the implementation details and have the .m use a NSMutableArray and to a consumer 
use an NSArray.

```
[self setCategories:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:categories]];    // this gives no Xcode warning
```

By using the [NSMutableAray arrayWithArray:] method, does it still prevent the consumer of my Class from mutating my categories array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done all you can in objc.

Your internal readwrite declaration needs a mutable array, so Xcode's complaining is right, you have to use a mutable for the setter.

The consumer can do everything with that object, even if it's declared as NSArray you can find out it's a NSMutableArray in reality and change it.

You can't prevent that. But your public declaration shows it should be assumed immutable. There's nothing more you can do.